# The Limitations of Vieta's Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I was attempting to find the roots of [$f(x)=2x^3+10x^2+5x−12$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556571/find-all-real-zeros-of-fx-2x310x25x-12/556820#556820) and since the the OP had already found one of the roots, I tried to recall a relation to help me find the other two easily. The first one that popped to mind were [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) for Cubic Polynomials:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=-\frac{b}{a}$$$$x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=\frac{c}{a}$$$$x_1x_2x_3=-\frac{d}{a}$$

But when I tried applying them, I found that they don't work. I've never actually used the relations to find roots like this before and frankly I've never seen anyone do it.

As stupid a question as this is, Why doesn't it work for the cubic I tried it on?
And also, in what other circumstances doesn't it work?

Please help me understand the limitations of these relations and try to be as simple as you can.

**EDIT**:These relations do work in helping to solve for the rest of the roots and it was sheer idiocy on my part that made me suspect that they didn't.

Comment: It works just fine.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Yes but didn't work in finding the other roots.

Comment: I have written out an answer.

Comment: @Nick: Can you provide an example for which they don't work? You most likely made a mistake.

Comment: @Gerard: Indeed I did. And I apologize for asking this question.

Comment: While the question was about Vieta's formulas, it's very important to note that a method you can use to solve a cubic when you know one of the roots is to divide the polynomial by $(x-\text{the root})$, which will leave you with a quadratic (and no remainder by the factor theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relations work just fine. We get $x_1+x_2+x_3=-5$. One of the roots, say $x_3$, is $-4$, so $x_1+x_2=-1$.

Similarly, $x_1x_2x_3=6$, so $x_1x_2=-\frac{3}{2}$.

Now $(x_1-x_2)^2=(x_1+x_2)^2-4x_1x_2=7$. So $x_1-x_2=\pm\sqrt{7}$. We know $x_1+x_2$, so we can easily find $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: Well, I could have done it another way, ($x_2=-3/(2x_1)$, substitute in $x_1+x_2=-1$, we get a quadratic). The identity $(x-y)^2=(x+y)^2-4xy$ is however, a nicer way to go, we keep symmetry until the very end.

Comment: Well, thank you for that logical insight. I never thought of that identity in helping me solve this.

Comment: You are welcome. That method is very old, dating back to neo-Babylonian times, before the Quadratic Formula.